# alias for a bash cmd with xargs for directories fails

Tags: linux, bash, shell, alias, xargs

I use a command to collect all my projects by searching for a common file (Jenkinsfile) because I want to execute a command in every project directory:

```
find . -name 'Jenkinsfile' | sed s/Jenkinsfile// |  xargs -L 1 bash -c '(cd $0 && git branch)'
```

To shorten this for future usage I tried to create an alias for it like this:

```
alias fgb="find . -name 'Jenkinsfile' | sed s/Jenkinsfile// |  xargs -L 1 bash -c 'cd $0 && git branch'"
```

But now I only get such error msgs:

```
./shared/authorization-provider/: line 0: cd: /usr/bin/bash: No such file or directory
```

What is wrong?

EDIT:

I found a solution:

```
alias fgb="find . -name 'Jenkinsfile' | sed s/Jenkinsfile// |  xargs -I {} bash -c 'cd {} && pwd && git branch' "
```

Answer (score 2):

> What is wrong?

`$0` is inside `"` quotes, so it is expanded to `/usr/bin/bash`. `cd $0` -> `cd /usr/bin/bash` -> `no such file or dir`.

The millennium long advice is: use a function, not an alias. Instead of an alias, write a function.

```
fgb() {
   find . -name 'Jenkinsfile' | sed s/Jenkinsfile// |  xargs -L 1 bash -c 'cd $0 && git branch'
}
```

Comment: Before I come back to the millennium long advise :D please let me understand your explanation: Which " quotes do you mean? The pair around the whole alias? Because $0 doesn't have these directly.

Comment: `alias fgb="blablabla cd $0 && blabla"` - one `"` after `=` and one `"` at the end. `The pair around the whole alias?` Yes. Try `echo alias fbg="......"` and see the output.

Comment: Even simpler try `alias fbg` and see what alias you defined.

Comment: Thank you. I played a bit with the variable. Now it works. Millennium must wait :)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Kamil you should try to use functions instead of the more or less obsolete aliases. And `find` is enough for what you want:

```
fgb() {
  find . -name 'Jenkinsfile' -execdir 'git branch' \;
}
```

`-execdir` runs its command argument from the directory in which a matching file was found.